# Python dataframe indexing - can not reindex?

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing

Indexing a panda dataframe using set_index or reindex did not work as intended. Am I missing something? Thanks for the help. See the example below. Use a.set_index(['Date']) getting same result

```
print(a)
a.reindex(['Date'])
print(a.index)
   Adj_Close      Close       Date       High        Low       Open Symbol  \
3  53.015032  54.799999 2016-01-04  54.799999  53.389999  54.320000   MSFT   
2  53.256889  55.049999 2016-01-05  55.389999  54.540001  54.930000   MSFT   
1  52.289462  54.049999 2016-01-06  54.400002  53.639999  54.320000   MSFT   
0  50.470697  52.169998 2016-01-07  53.490002  52.070000  52.700001   MSFT   

     Volume  price_gap    target  
3  53778000        NaN  0.479999  
2  34079700   0.130001  0.119999  
1  39518900  -0.729999 -0.270001  
0  56564900  -1.349998 -0.530003
```

Comment: Sorry the post missed print(a.index) result. See below Int64Index([3, 2, 1, 0], dtype='int64')

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
a.set_index(['Date'], inplace=True)
```

As listed here:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

Or, if you want a new dataframe:

```
b = a.set_index(['Date'])
```